# How to configure keycloak with NGINX for J2EE web applicaton?

Tags: java, ssl, nginx, jboss, keycloak

**How previously my web-application setup with keycloak?**

1. Installed keycloak in server machine
2. Deployed the web-application in Jboss server
3. Added the keycloak certificate into the Java Keytool in the machine where web-app running.
4. Made following changes in Standalone.xml file of JBOSS ES6.4

**Added Extension**

```
 <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-subsystem"/>
```

**Added security-domain**

```
<security-domain name="keycloak">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
 </security-domain>
```

**Added Connector**

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
                <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="initcert" password="keycloak" certificate-key-file="C:\Code_Base\keycloak_certificates\keycloak_server\keycloak.jks" protocol="TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2" verify-client="false"/>
</connector>
```

**Add SubSystem**

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
                <secure-deployment name="MyApp.war">
                    <realm>MYRealm</realm>
                    <resource>MyApp</resource>
                    <use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
                    <auth-server-url>https://<Server IP>/auth/</auth-server-url>
                    <ssl-required>NONE</ssl-required>
                    <credential name="secret">5c9f6ea3-3448-4569-b6c4-a9e62de4db52</credential>
                </secure-deployment>
            </subsystem>
```

So above changes working fine and my web application showing keycloak login page and after successful login its showing my web app Home page.

Now my requirement to run Keycloak in HA mode with load balancer NGINX So NGINX will be in front end and NGINX will decide which keycloak to point when hitting `https://<NGINX IP ADDRESS>/auth` and below things already done .

**What already done?**

1. Installed HA Keycloak in Node1 and Running.
2. Installed HA Keycloak in Node2 and Running.
3. Installed common Database(Used by above keycloak) in Node3 and Running.
4. Installed NGINX in Node4 and Running.
5. Configure Both keycloak(Step1 and Step2) with NGINX
6. Now NGINX url (`https://<IP ADDRESS>/auth`) showing login page of Keycloak and login also working.

Now can someone please tell me what changes i have to do in Jboss so it will work with new setup.

Answer (score -1):

You basically need to do the same configuration, but in **standalone-ha.xml** instead of **standalone.xml**...

Comment: But now more than one keycloak So i have to do make two entry for certificates?
I have to give url of NGINX not the keycloak but certificate is a problem.

Comment: Why don't you make SSL termination at Nginx level?

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit .I already generate certificate for keycloak1,keycloak2,SSL termination for nginx .Now in my local machine i deployed the war file in Jboss server .Now can you tell me what changes in local Jboss ?